# How to rewrite proxified HTTP requests in Charles without changing IP address/TCP Port of the original packet?

Tags: proxy, http, http-proxy

I am using Charles to intercept and rewrite a certain query in proxified HTTP requests as following:

HTTP request --->> Proxifier --->> Charles Socks proxy ---->> HTTP proxy --->>  HTTP server

The problem is that after rewriting HTTP requests, Charles sends them directly to the HTTP server ignoring the fact that they are proxified. I have compared the original proxified HTTP requests (without Charles interception) with the Charles-rewritten HTTP requests in Wireshark and found out that the HTTP proxy IP/port changed to the HTTP server IP/port! certainly as a result of Charles doing unnecessary DNS lookup based on HTTP server hostname, How to go about this problem?

Comment: just to clear any confusion I am using the verb/adjective proxified to refer to the HTTP proxy not to Charles Socks proxy and Proxifier is used only for redirecting HTTP traffic to Charles.

Comment: I'd like also to dismiss the suggestion of setting external proxy in Charles to the desired HTTP proxy to overcome the problem since there are many HTTP proxies.